# Call function within prototype

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Test()
{
    console.log('constructor');


    this.chaninFunction = function(){
        console.log('chain me up');
    }
}

Test.prototype.callme = function(first_argument) {
    console.log('called him');

    this.callBack = function()
    {
        console.log('call back');
    }
};

Test.prototype.message = function(first_argument) {
    console.log('message him');
};

var test = new Test();
test.chaninFunction();
test.callme();
test.callme().callBack(); //Error undefined
test.message();

</script>
```

Hi,

I am learning JS at the moment. having experience few situation.

Is there a way i can call the function within the prototype? the above testing i have done result in error. How can i access the function within prototype, or i can't?

Comment: You are attaching `callBack` to the instance itself, so after calling `test.callme();`, you can just do `test.callback();`. However, I don't know why this would be useful.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for helping :) test.callback() result error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Test> has no method 'callback'

Comment: @user775735: no it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/LzYBT/

Comment: As I said, the function would only be available *after* you called `test.callme()`.

Comment: `callme` should do `return this;` if you want to be able to do `test.callme().callback()`.

Comment: @cookiemonster leave in the answer i will vote you up sir :) Thanks it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're saying you want to be able to chain the `.callback()` after a call to `.callme()`.

Chaining is very simple. The previous method you called simply needs to return an object that contains the next method you want to call. So in your case, both methods are on the same object, so you just need to do `return this;`.

```
Test.prototype.callme = function(first_argument) {
    console.log('called him');

    this.callBack = function()
    {
        console.log('call back');
    }

    return this;
};
```